# 20.04 client vpn connects successfully but times out when connecting to vpn required website

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN .conf file to connect to a company vpn. I need to be connected to this VPN so that I can access domains that are not searchable by default DNS. 
After successfully connecting to the vpn using Network Manager, I can access all websites EXCEPT for the ones that need the vpn. I have multiple other vpns that work perfectly fine.  
 I get timed out errors on those that require this vpn to connect to them. If I ping or nslookup those vpn required websites they connect successfully but don't work on browsers or applications.

The following is my .conf file:

```
#-- Configuration Generated By Viscosity --#

#viscosity startonopen false
#viscosity usepeerdns true
#viscosity dns split
#viscosity protocol openvpn
#viscosity autoreconnect true
#viscosity name XXXX
#viscosity dhcp true
remote XXX.net yyyy udp
nobind
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
persist-tun
persist-key
pull
tls-client
ca ca.crt
cert cert.crt
key key.key
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-GCM
connect-timeout 5
web-ca ca.crt
tls-crypt tlscrypt.key
```

Comment: Never heard of a web site that NEEDS a VPN. Please edit your question and explain this statement.

Comment: It's a comany vpn that needs to be on so that my laptop has access to company domains in different environments. Let me know if I can clarify anything else

Comment: So the web site does not need VPN you need VPN to access them. That makes more sense.

Comment: Correct. For example, with VPN, on browser I got xyz.com it should connect, but it times out. But if I run ping xyz.com or nslookup xzy.com it connects successfully.

Comment: What you are now describing is simply a VPN issue. You may want to edit the title and make that clear.